# iPhone 11 failing to connect to 3g

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

For the first time in a long while I am to a location without any 4G or LTE - **only 3G**. Unfortunately, no matter what I do, I am failing to coax my iPhone 11 even as close as to receive/send any data over it including switching voice and data on the phone’s secondary line (the one with a plan for roaming) to 3G. Text messages seem to go fine.

Here are my current data configuration:

[image: main mobile data screen]

[image: secondary line data screen]

Is there anything possibly wrong with the configurations that might be a quick fix? Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the problem was with the cell service provider to which my phone was connecting by default. It seems it was not respecting roaming agreement with my provider. Switching to another provider manually solved the issue.